# Wired connection problem through router

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm having trouble to connect my Ubuntu 11.10 to internet through ethernet. I installed a router to get Wi-Fi and now (by a wired connection) I can't have internet with ubuntu (but I can with Windows 7). I see several attempts per minute of the network-manager to get a connection, but after a minute it stops trying.
Here are a couple of outputs from key files:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

and

```
ifconfig -a

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:76:e4:a6:e8  
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:76ff:fee4:a6e8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:117 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:117
          TX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:12221 (12.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:582 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:582 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:46024 (46.0 KB)  TX bytes:46024 (46.0 KB)
```

I tried reconnecting the modem and the router and reconnecting the ethernet cable but nothing... I tried other solutions from other posts (this one has a similar issue [Wired connection not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18311/wired-connection-not-working)) but again nothing.
My IP is dynamic.

A couple of things I see and did:

- I see no inet addr, only inet6. I ignored ipv6 from the internet connections, and restarted the network-manager service and nothing.
- A difference with the post I mentioned is the RX packets with errors I have, is this a clue of the problem?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `dhclient eth0` (It will get you an IP address from the router: if it is configured to do so).

If that method works go to network connections; select your wired connection and click edit; go to IPv4 settings tab; change the method to Automatic (DHCP).

Or you can simply add the following lines to /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: sorry...dthat didn't work. The "dhclient eth0" just hangs...and the modifications in the interfaces file make ubuntu don't recognize my connection. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Just wanted to say it worked for me (exact same issue, exact same OSes).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with wired connection: Now I have overcome it as follow.
Use the terminal:

```
1. sudo dhclient eth0 <-- will work but I have to do it every time I turn on the computer.(Should it fail, on/off the wireless using wcid. It works most of the time.)
2. try plug and unplug the cable <-- I tried very often but sooner or later the whole   socket will be damage.
3 Best choice so far: IT WORKS.
terminal: gedit dhclient eth0 
pasword:......
```

Your doc must be modified. See below

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# auto eth0
# iface eth0 inet static
#  address 192.168.0.254
#  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

save and exit. This should work now. 
Good Luck.